# Sql to get distinct row where all columns match except one

Tags: sql

Hi i have code which gives me output like below. Its checking data on 2 different days i.e. kry function which is a varchar field.

Using where key in ('Abc26', 'Abc27')

```
Key     code   col1   col2   col3
Abc27   esp    4      54     73
Abc26   esp    3      54     32
Abc27   aud    23     32     77
Abc27   hkd    37     2      3
```

I need output as only 1 row but given the condition that data should be present for both days i.e Abc27 and Abc26 but only display latest i.e. Abc27 row.

Required output

```
Key    code   col1   col2   col3
Abc27  esp    4      54     73
```

Comment: But the matching record you are showing us has a counterpart with _two_ columns, not one, which are not in agreement.  Can you fix your data?

Comment: Both days? I see no dates/days.

Comment: How do you know what the latest row is?  And what if there are multiple days but there are gaps?  Also, provide a database tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` with correlated sub-query :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.code = t.code AND t1.key <> t.key) AND
      t.key = (SELECT MAX(t1.key) FROM table t1 WHERE t1.code = t.code);
```

If your *DBMS* supports *window* function that you can do instead :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY code) AS Code_cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY key DESC) AS seq
      FROM table t
     ) t
WHERE Code_cnt > 1 AND seq = 1;
```